# Airflow - Using an upstream task for multiple downstream tasks

Tags: airflow

Okay I apologize if this is a dumb question, because it seems so obvious that it should work.  But I can't find it documented, and as are examining our options as we look to build a new data pipeline, I really want this to be a feature...

Can multiple downstream processes be dependent on a single upstream process, where the upstream process only runs once.  In other words, can I extract a table one time, and then load it to my data warehouse, and have multiple aggregations that are dependent on that load being complete?

For a bit more information, we are attempting to go to an asynchronous extract-load-transform where the extract is started, and then the loads and transforms finish as soon as they have the subset of tables they need from the extract.

Comment: The extract is running against the application database.  Tables are extracted to files, moved to the reporting database server, and loaded into the reporting database.  At that point there are a large number of transforms to create the data mart.  Those transforms are reliant on many different extract tables.

In most data pipelines models, one would do the full extract, then the full load, then start running transforms.  However, we are trying to make it so that tables are loaded from the extract files as soon as the files are ready, and transforms run as soon as they have their data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For the "as soon as ... ready" part, Airflow can be really helpful for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to me like a usual DAG with unusual wording. I understand the required structure like this:

```
extract_table_task \
                   |- task1_do_stuff
                   |- task2_do_some_other_stuff
                   |- task3_...
```

Or in Airflow code:

```
extract_table_task.set_downstream(task1_do_stuff)
extract_table_task.set_downstream(task2_do_some_other_stuff)
extract_table_task.set_downstream(task3_...)
```

Then make sure to select the correct trigger rules for your workflow, e.g. if some tasks should run even if something went wrong: https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding the question, yes, you can set downstream tasks to be dependent on the success of an upstream task.

We use dummyOperators in a lot of cases similar to this sample DAG:
[image]

In the case we want the dummyOperator to kick off first and do something, before the downstream tasks kick off. This makes clearing out failed runs easier as well as we can simply clear the dummy operator and downstream tasks at the same time.

You can use the `depends_on_past=True` parameter to require upstream tasks run before the downstream tasks are queued, otherwise they can be skipped based on logic in the upstream task.